# Can Windows server install SSL certificate on clients without permission?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ssl-certificate

And if not, what kind of permission is required?

I have a computer (Windows 8.1) that I bring to work. At home, I just discovered a trusted root certificate from a Windows 10 server that I interact with and partially manage at work. I don't recall ever installing the certificate on my own computer.

So I don't know if this was the result of:

1. An automated process that happened when I installed the "Launchpad" Windows client connection. ( Launchpad also resulted in the server backing up my hard disk without my permission, so I suspect this is where the invasion occurred ).
2. Some kind of "push" process initiated by someone other than me on the server.
3. I installed it myself for some reason and forgot.

I'm leaning toward #1, since it seems to be a somewhat invasive program.

Can/should I remove it? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2):

I can suspect that the certificate came to you automatically through group policies. There is an option to automatically (without end user intervention) distribute custom certificates to clients when they needed to perform work duties. Or it was installed by using application you use for work.

To answer other questions, you really should understand the boundaries and responsibility. That is:

- is this computer your own devices or it was issued by your employer?
- if it is employer's computer, then there should be a signed document that describes relying party responsibility and liability regarding to device management.
- if it is your own computer: does company policy supports BYOD (bring your own device) policy?
- if BYOD is allowed, then there should be a document that describes relying party responsibility and liability regarding to device management.

ultimately, you should contact company's system administrators or helpdesk in order to find answers to your questions.